# Return yes/no from select, no flow control or adding tables to the database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running a select statement checking for the existence of output froma  sub-query. Its current form is the following.

```
select exists(subquery)
```

Now, the parameters of the solution are:

- The output must be a single row, with a single entry, either 'Yes' or "no
- Any form of flow control is disallowed
- Adding a table to the database is disallowed (for example to 'translate' 1 to Yes and 0 to No through a query)

I'm kind of at a loss. My best idea is to produce the '1-yes, 0-no' 'table' via subquery, but I haven't the slightest how that can be done.

Comment: Why such limitations in the first place? A simple way can be to use a `CASE WHEN` expression, if that doesn't counts as "flow control".

Comment: Nope, flow control is explicitly defined by the parameters as 'if, case etc.' I do not know why those limitations are in place, they were just handed to me, though if a solution is absolutely impossible with them in place, the one to breach would be the 'extra table' limitation - flow control is off limits to the bitter end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not pretty, but you can cobble a look up table together with `SELECT` and `UNION` in a sub-query, then join to that from your `EXISTS` query.

Set up a really lame table:

```
create table tbl (value integer);
insert into tbl
select 1;
```

Then the query:

```
select
  a.answer
from 
  (select exists(select 1 from tbl where value = 3) as value) as e
  join
  (select 1 as value, 'yes' as answer
   union
   select 0, 'no'
  ) as a
    on 
      a.value = e.value
```

In this case, the table `tbl` only has one row and one column, which contains a `1`, so the `EXISTS` returns a `0` and the outer query returns a `no`.

Here's a SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4f9ef/2/0

Comment: Nice! Normally this isn't within parameters, because of create table, BUT I managed to tweak it: 

select a.answer
from (select exists(subquery) as exist) as v, 
    (select 1 as value, 'yes' as answer union select 0, 'no') as a
where v.exist = a.value. If you wish to edit/add an answer to mirror it, I'll pick your answer, or I can go ahead and answer if you'd rather not have to! Thanks!

Comment: The create table here is just to create a valid `exists` query; it's not technically part of the solution, since you already have a subquery you're working with. But I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a `case` expression:

```
select (case when exists(subquery) then 'yes' else 'no' end)
```

Personally, though, I prefer your version which returns `0` or `1` instead of `'no'` or `'yes'`.

Comment: Case is flow control. I'm not allowed to use it.

And neither am I allowed to settle for '0-1'. 'Yes-No' is the requirement.